# how to set custom column name csv_from_result in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, csv, export

I'm using `csv_from_result` helper function in codeigniter.
It gives database table name as column names in csv file.

How can i set custom column names in csv file.

Ex: my table contains fields like `number, name`
I want these fields in csv as `Course number, Course name`

Following way works fine

```
SELECT number as course_number, name as course_name from courses;
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do its really easy as you are using select statement you can do that, you can create your columns alias as string with space but should be in quotes

```
'SELECT number as "course number", name as "course name" from courses';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = "SOME mysql query";

    $csv = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result);

    //edit $csv , remove first line and replace it with custom column names
```

Use this library to do your CSV manipulation.

http://pear.php.net/package/File_CSV_DataSource

You could possibly tell it to ignore the first line in csv results, and then replace it with your own values?

Hope this helps